# ASP.NET MVC application error - controller method for a GET not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My ASP.NET MVC app is recording errors (via ELMAH) for `GET` requests on controller methods that do not support `GET`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveChoiceSingle(int sessionId, int actionId, int itemNumber, string response)
{
    MultipleChoice.SaveSingleResponse(sessionId, actionId, itemNumber, response);

    return new JsonResult()
               {
                   Data = string.Empty
               };
}
```

The ASP.NET MVC views do not allow a user to send a `GET` request, so I suspect a client's browser extension is making the `GET` requests.

What is the "best practice" to send as a response so that it is not logged as an application/server error?

- 400 Bad Request
- 404 Not Found
- 405 Method Not Allowed

Comment: I don't know the official best practice, but I like 405 since it's clear what the issue is. On the other hand, depending on whether this is a public-facing API, you might want to use 404 instead, to minimize the amount of information you give out to a random "get"-er.

Comment: so something like this...
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SaveChoiceSingle()
    {
       return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed);
    }

Comment: Oh; I was assuming you'd use a filter attribute or something in a base controller to take care of it. I wouldn't suggest cluttering up your controller with new action methods just to return error codes!